# Setting global rates in trickled

Tags: debian, bandwidth

I try to limit download-upload bandwidth for each users on Debian.

```
trickled -d DOWNLOAD_LIMIT -u UPLOAD_LIMIT
```

is supposed to limit bandwidth completely (according to some articles on Web). But it has no effect in my case.
I also tried

```
trickle -d DOWNLOAD_LIMIT -u UPLOAD_LIMIT APPLICATION
```

It runs the application and limits take effect. What is the problem with the first command?